# Changed MYSQL database table a little bit, need this query to work as before

Tags: mysql, datatable

So this seems like a simple little problem, but I haven't been successful with getting this to work properly. I have a comments table, a posts table, and a notifications table. Previously I stored the postID in a column called "uniqueID" for notifications and for comments.  Now I have changed it so that the comments unique id is stored in that column instead. So all I need to do is for each row that is a comment in notifications, go to the comments table where uniqueID==id and then return the value in that table called postID.

Here is a photo showing my question better.

http://i41.tinypic.com/nyzolg.png

---

The information from the photo is:

```
Table: Notifications

id  UserID  FromID  UniqueID    Action  State   Read_Date   Date
1   1       2       1           1       0       0           1325993600
2   1       6       2           1       0       0           1325993615
3   1       2       1           2       0       0           1325993622
4   1       6       2           2       0       0           1325993661
5   2       6       2           2       0       0           1325993661
```

Action = 1 means UniqueID identifies a row in Posts;
Action = 2 means UniqueID identifies a row in Comments.

```
Table: Posts

id  ToID    FromID  Post        State   Date
1   1       2       Hey         0       1325993600
2   1       6       okay yeah   0       1325993615

Table: Comments

ID  PostID  FromID  Comment     State   Date
1   1       2       lol         0       1325993622
2   1       6       ohh         0       1325993661
```

So, in the Notifications table where action is 2, the UniqueID's are for the 'id' in the Comments table.
What I want to return is the PostID, so in the query it would just be as if the UniqueID was this instead:

```
1
2
1
1
1
```

But the UniqueID would stay the same where Action is 1.

---

My current query is this, and it worked fine before I changed my database values around.

```
$notificationsq = mysql_query("
SELECT
    N.*,
    P.*,
MAX(N.date) AS newDate
 FROM
    notifications N,
    posts
WHERE
    N.userID='$session'
AND
    (
            (
                   N.action='1'
                AND
                   (N.state = 0 OR N.state=1)
             )
            OR
                N.action='2'
     )
AND P.state='0'
AND
    N.uniqueID=P.id
GROUP BY
    N.uniqueID
ORDER BY
    N.state ASC,
    newDate DESC

") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ummm... what?  Some more details of the table structure and what exactly you're trying to accomplish would be useful.

Comment: It shows my tables in the photo. I'm not sure how else to explain it

Comment: Do you mean 'a comments table, a posts table and a notifications table'?  Similarly, you say 'stored the postID in a row called "uniqueID"' but I suspect you mean 'stored the postID in a column called "uniqueID"'.  If so, please don't misuse the jargon; it makes it very hard to help you if you call a column a row.

Comment: In addition to the database/table issue, after reading the question a couple of times, I'm pretty sure you refer to a row when you mean column.  Is your issue trying to perform the dereference?

Comment: Yeah, I do mean column not row sorry about that. I was typing this up in a hurry. But yes you are right. And in the photo is has the name of the table above each

Comment: I've transferred the data from the image to the question (I must be mad) and I've changed database to table and row to column.  Please double check that I did that right.

Comment: Now I'm just confused about what your problem is.  Are you trying to update the information in Notifications, or are you trying to rewrite the query to pull the PostID from Comments (so you're going to need to add Comments to the tables and an appropriate joining condition)?  Are you going to have to deal with LEFT OUTER JOINs?  You really should be using the explicit JOIN notation (standard since 1992) and not the archaic (standard since 1986) notation with a comma-separated list of tables in the FROM clause.  Is the fifth row of data in Notifications accurate?

Comment: Is there a reason why the database is so lacking in normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "C.*" to your select clause, "comments C" to your from clause, and change " N.action='2'" to

```
(N.action='2' and (N.uniqueId = C.id))
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. The current value in the notifications column uniqueID is not the id that i want to compare with, I want to get the postID from the comments table where N.uniqueID=C.id, I believe the only way in doing this is to create a new "column", as I did with MAX(N.date) AS newDate

Comment: I suspect there are a few things I'm not understanding about your question and the associated data.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, no it's okay, it's a a little complicated, and I have trouble explaining exactly what I'm trying to do for that reason, Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: You might want to spend some time thinking through how to edit the question for clarification, as well as answer Jonathan's question about the fifth row of the notifications table.

Comment: Well, I think I have almost got the solution